# Unable to edit the robot file in Pycharm in Mac

Tags: macos, pycharm, robotframework

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to edit the robot file in PyCharm. I have installed intellibot plugin but still facing issues in editing the robot file every time. I am not sure if there is any keyboard lock which happened but every-time I want to type something it doesn't happen.

I am using Mac OS 10.13.6. Intellibot version is 4.1

Comment: this should not have happened, this is nothing to do with intellibot plugin at all. Have you unknowingly installed and enabled idevim plugin ? if yes, then disable that , so that normal operations can be resumed.

Comment: just a hint for you, I use VS code it's more faster.